# Eigenvectors to find invariant lines of transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Transformation *T* is represented by the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$. Find the invariant lines under the transformation.

I've found the eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvectors :
$$\lambda_1=1 \;\;\;\;\; \vec{v_1}=\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\lambda_2=-1 \;\;\;\;\; \vec{v_2}=\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right)$$
This would correspond to the invariant lines $L_1 : x=0 \;$ and $L_2 : y=x$ . The answer is supposed to be $L_2 : y=x+c \;$, which I can get by using another approach. Since eigenvectors only show invariant lines passing through the origin, how can I find those that do not?